# Limiting points of coaxial system of spheres

Tags: geometry

Find the limiting points of coaxial system of spheres determined by the spheres $x^2+y^2+z^2+3x-3y+6=0$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2-6y+6z+6=0$. what I observed is that the first equation does not represent a sphere(because radius is imaginary). Can limiting points found for imaginary spheres. Can any one help?